# OAuth2 provider using Spring Security return accesstokens in json; Need to get Token in XML format

Tags: spring, oauth, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I want to write `OAuth2` provider which will return access token in `XML` not in `JSON`. I am using Spring Security (i.e. http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html) for writing `OAuth2` provider.

I followed some tutorials on GIT but could not write provider which can return  response of `/oauth/token` in `XML` format.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible by adding JAXB filters as shown below

Comment: <mvc:annotation-driven>
  <mvc:message-converters>
   <bean
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.http.converter.jaxb.JaxbOAuth2AccessTokenMessageConverter" />
   <bean
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.http.converter.jaxb.JaxbOAuth2ExceptionMessageConverter" />
  </mvc:message-converters>
 </mvc:annotation-driven>